# How to split the string into half and extract the second part?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, error-handling, scrapy

```
a = "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.media-allrecipes.com%2Fuserphotos%2F4418848.jpg"
output = re.split("=", a)[1]
print(output)
```

output : https%3A%2F%2Fimages.media-allrecipes.com%2Fuserphotos%2F4418848.jpg

I want to apply this to a whole column I tried getting the output in two ways but it gives me errors. Also the column has some rows with no values can that affect the output?

```
mexican['Image'] = mexican['Image'].str.split("=")[1]
```

gives error :

> ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2982)

```
for i in mexican['Image']:
  mexican["Image"] = re.split("=", i)[1]
```

gives error :

> IndexError: list index out of range

### Solution :

I was facing problem because I had Nan values in my column. So I tried using try-except method for this case

```
for i in range(len(data['Image'])):
    try:
        data['Image'][i]=(data['Image'][i].split('='))[1]
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: You modifying the `mexican` list while iterating it. Did you mean something like: `for i in range(len(mexican['Image']): mexican['Image'][i] = re.split("=", mexican['Image'][i])[1]` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp still give and error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You also need to check that the array returned has length = 2. Ex: `for i in range(len(mexican['Image'])): if '=' in mexican['Image'][i]: mexican['Image'][i] = mexican['Image'][i].split("=")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the second part like this

```py
s = "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.media- 
allrecipes.com%2Fuserphotos%2F4418848.jpg"
s2 = s[len(s)//2:]
print(s2)
```

Comment: I want this done for the whole column not just one value as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
You are using "split" wrong

You have to do this.

```
a = "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.media-allrecipes.com%2Fuserphotos%2F4418848.jpg"
output = a.split("=")[1]
print(output)
```

Solution 2:
You can also use a regex for this

```
import re

a = "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.media-allrecipes.com%2Fuserphotos%2F4418848.jpg"
output = re.search("=(.*)" , a)
if output != None: print(output.group(1))
```

Solution 3:
right usage of "split" With a for loop and dataset:

```
for index, row in mexican.iterrows():
     mexican.loc[index, "Image"] = row["Image"].split("=")[1]
```

Comment: For the 3rd solution instead of putting the output in variable "output" how can I put the output value in the column itself?

Comment: what do you mean with columns?

Comment: and what is "mexican["Image"]" exactly

Comment: is it a dictionary?

Comment: "mexican" is the dataset and "Image" is the column in which there are urls

Comment: I didn't test solution 3 but I took inspiration from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367710/replace-values-in-pandas-data-frame-within-a-loop . Is this what you mean?